# Language Caching Across Sites in OpenCart

Tags: caching, opencart, browser-cache

I have a setup with 2 OpenCart sites.  There is an English version of the site, then there is a German version of the site (which was cloned from the English version) on a subdomain.

It seems that the German version is caching English text in the browser somehow.  Sometimes when going to the German site, some text shows up in English, clearing browser cache fixes the issue, but then it will come back after a while.

I'm wondering if the English site could be caching some text which then inadvertently shows up on the German site?  I haven't seen any German showing up on the English version though.

Also, on the German site, the front end language is set to German but the backend is still set to English, could this be part of the problem?

I'm still a bit new to OpenCart, so I'm not sure how this caching works.

Comment: I don't think it's the caching but the cookie. If you visit a *English site* first, it will store the language ID into the session (cookie) so if you visit the *German site* afterwards OC thinks you are willing to see the *English* content. Even after few days without clearing the session/cookies this may happen if you enter the *German site* first. So, try to delete your cookies and then visit the *German site* first. It should be OK. But adequately if you now visit the *English site* it should be translated to German. This is not a real issue if you are *directing* the customers properly.

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense.  Is there anything I can do to make the two sites use separate session cookies?  The German site was cloned from the English site, so maybe it's not distinguishing?

I can't seem to reliably recreate the issue, if I clear cache, visit the English site, then go to German it's hit or miss.  I just see it sometimes and others have reported it.  I've never seen any German on the English site though (German isn't set up as a front-end language there).  Maybe if I delete English as a front-end language on the German site, will it always fall back to German?

Comment: Hmm, never tried it, but I guess you cannot loose anything by trying it :-)